# How does spell upgrades work?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

This might be a noob question but one just needs to be on the required character level to get the "upgrades" on spells or on the required class levels?

As in eldritch blast upgrades at 5th level character or 5th level warlock?

Comment: Hi V. Ace, it looks like you might have created two accounts. Please see [this help center article](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) on how to merge them.